# Don't know how manipulate strings

Tags: java, string, character

Take as input S, a string. Write a function that replaces every odd character with the character having just higher ASCII code and every even character with the character having just lower ASCII code. Print the value returned.

```
 package assignments;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class strings_odd_even_char {
     static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String str = scn.nextLine();

         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + 2) {
             char ch = str.charAt(i);
             ch = (char)((ch + 1));
             System.out.println(ch);
         }
         for (int j = 1; j < str.length(); j = j + 2) {
             char ch = str.charAt(j);
             ch = (char)((ch - 1));
             System.out.print(ch);
         }

     }

 }
```

The problem with my code is that it is first printing the values for all the odd characters and then for even characters but what I want is that they get printed in proper sequence like for input --> abcg , the output should be --> badf .

Comment: You only need to iterate one time but do different operation `(char+1)` or `(char-1)` depending on the `i`.

Comment: The reason it is doing that is you are using the first loop for the even and the second loop for the odd.  if you want to print both together in order you have to combine them in some way.  Think of instead of doing 2 loops, do 1 and check i for even or odd.

Comment: Only iterate once. And decide whether do convert up or down by using i%2==0

Comment: @Suryansh Manav do yourself a favor and get familiar with java class naming convention.

Comment: Consider indenting your code properly if you would like people to read it.

Comment: @khelwood will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

Just use one loop that handles both characters:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + 2) {
  char ch = str.charAt(i);
  ch = (char) (ch + 1);
  System.out.print(ch);

  if (i + 1 < str.length()) {
    ch = str.charAt(i + 1);
    ch = (char) (ch - 1);
    System.out.print(ch);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to iterate one time but do different operation `(char+1)` or `(char-1)` depending on the `i`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = scn.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(i % 2 == 0) { // even
            ch += 1;
        } else {         // odd
            ch -= 1;
        }
        System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd hold the "incremenet" value in a variable and alternate it between `+1` and `-1` as I go voer the characters:

```
private static String change(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    int increment = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        sb.append((char)(s.charAt(i) + increment));
        increment *= -1;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two loops, but you only need one. You can use the `%` operator to tell if `i` is even or odd, and then either subtract or add accordingly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   char ch = str.charAt(i);
   if(i % 2 == 0) {
      ch = (char)((ch + 1));
      System.out.println(ch);
   } else {
      ch = (char)((ch - 1));
      System.out.print(ch);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one `for loop`, to do that you will need to check whether the current index is even or odd. if current index is even you will increment char and print, if it is odd you will decrement char and print.  to check if even or odd using `%` operator

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   char ch = str.charAt(i);
   if(i%2 == 0)   {         
      ch = ch + 1;
      System.out.println(ch); 
      continue;
    }
  ch = ch - 1;
  System.out.println(ch);
}
```